# How detect string concatenation in logger statements?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

Is there a way to configure the Checkstyle, PMD, or FindBugs Maven plugins to detect code like this:

```
logger.debug("string" + stringVariable);
```

Instead of:

```
logger.debug("format string {}", stringVariable);
```

Comment: I asked myself what the problem with the first line was. Found the explaination here: Performance (http://slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance )

Answer (score 5):

Excellent question!

I' ve just found a collection of additional rules for findbugs which covers your case (and some more): https://github.com/eller86/findbugs-slf4j

Check `SLF4J_FORMAT_SHOULD_BE_CONST` should allow you to find string concatenation inside format string.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the post of Slava (which should suite your needs best) there are methods in findbugs to check for String issues (e.g. SBSC_USE_STRINGBUFFER_CONCATENATION) and also [fb-contrib](http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has patterns to check for that. The relevant for you should be:

- ISB_TOSTRING_APPENDING
- ISB_INEFFICIENT_STRING_BUFFERING
- ISB_EMPTY_STRING_APPENDING
- ITC_INHERITANCE_TYPE_CHECKING
- ...

FB-contrib nearly adds 200 bug patterns to findbugs so its really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

4 years late but worth posting as the question asked also for PMD. Here is the syntax for creating a PMD rule with XPath (the way to configure a rule is pretty short from here):

```
//PrimaryPrefix/
Name[matches(@Image,'logger.trace|logger.debug|logger.info|logger.warn|logger.error|logger.fatal')]
/../../PrimarySuffix//ArgumentList/*[1]//AdditiveExpression
```

Answer (score -1):

do like this.

refer [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
logger.debug(String.format("format string %s ", stringVariable));
```

or

refer [MessageFormat.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

```
logger.debug(MessageFormat.format("format string {0}", new Object[]{stringVariable }));
```

Comment: Ui! Two comments:  1) String concatenation with "+" is normally compiled into using a StringBuilder, which is sometimes acceptable. Using String.format in that case makes it worse, as this formatting is more complicated than the simple concatenation.  2) The qeustion was, how to detect the string concatenation in logger calls, not how to better handle them. In fact, the question already contains an example of a logger, that already implements formatting.